# How to group records in date ranges based on a certain field

Tags: ms-access

I am currently using a continuous form to a show a set of data that results in the following format (each line being one record):

```
1/04/13     Person1
31/03/13    Person1
30/03/13    Person1
29/03/13    Person2
28/03/13    Person1
```

There are 100s of these records and I would like to condense it to the following:

```
30/03/13 - 1/04/13     Person1
29/03/13               Person2
28/03/13               Person1
```

The data is from a query, so can be manipulated at the SQL level before it even gets to the form stage. I am also comfortable using macros or VBA to manipulate the form. However, I still haven't been able to find a suitable way of doing this.

I realise that this is typical behaviour for a report, but since I eventually want this to be embedded in another form as a subform, I can't use reports (can't create a subreport in a form unless I am missing something).

Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good description of the problem.  Try building your source query like this (assuming the fields are called `MyDate` and `MyPerson` and the source table is `MyTable`):

```
Select Person, min(MyDate) as StartDate, max(MyDate) as EndDate
from MyTable
group by Person
```

This gives you 3 fields that you can drop into your form.

#### Edit

Now that we have a more complete picture, the task just got more complicated, but you still have options assuming the 'events' between people don't overlap (if they do, then I can't think of how to create eventIDs afterward).  In the absence of an EventID, you'll have to create one:

1. First, you need to move your data to a new table so that you can reorder it and add a blank field for the event ID you'll be adding in step 2.
   1a. Copy MyTable into a new table. Add an extra field called EventID.
   1b. To populate this table, first `Delete * from TmpTbl`
   1c. Then something like:
   `Insert into TmpTbl.* from MyTable order by MyDate,MyPerson`
2. This code will look through your temp table (TmpTbl as i call it) and add an event id.

   ```
   Sub AddEventIDs()
   Dim rst As Recordset
   Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TmpTbl")
   Dim LastPerson As String
   Dim EventID As Integer
   docmd.setwarnings false
   While rst.EOF = False
       If LastPerson <> rst.Fields("MyPerson") Then EventID = EventID + 1
       LastPerson = rst.Fields("MyPerson")
       rst.Edit
       rst.Fields("EventID") = EventID
       rst.Update
       rst.MoveNext
   Wend
   docmd.setwarnings true
   End Sub
   ```
3. On the On Load event of your form, add in the 2 queries and the sub routine from #1 and #2.
4. Your final query will be:

   ```
   Select MyPerson, EventID, min(MyDate) as StartDate, max(MyDate) as EndDate
   from MyTable
   group by MyPerson,EventID
   ```

Comment: Thank you for that quick reply, it is extremely close to what I wanted (in fact I immediately changed my form thinking it was exactly what I needed), however, since it groups by person, two different records can show to be covering the same days (when in fact they are not). I have updated my original question to show what I mean since I can't seem to properly show it in this reply. Please let me know if this reply doesn't make much sense.

Comment: So person 1 has 2 date ranges you want to display on separate rows. Is there any way to distinguish between these "events"? like, some sort of event ID?

Comment: Technically, the number of date ranges can't be determined before hand. With 100s of records, each person could feature multiple times (essentially, I want to be able to group consecutive days in which the same person featured). Also, yes, I do have a unique ID stored for each record

Comment: That makes sense, there's options here.  But i need to re-ask my question. By 'event id', I mean a way to distinguish each group of 'consecutive days'. In your example, Person A would have 2 unique Event IDs (perhaps 001 and 003) and Person B would only have 1 (perhaps 002). If you don't, and you can't add one to the source table, then the problem just got more complicated. Do you have an event ID like that?

Comment: Also, can you tell us more about your source table? What other fields are in it, etc.

Comment: Ahh no, I don't have event id's to distinguish grouped ranges. I currently don't have anything sorting these records into groups so no event id's can be generated unfortunately. My table consists of 3 things: a unique id; a date; a person. The person field is linked to another table containing different people records. The fields in that table are arbitrary: unique id; firstname; lastname.

Comment: I updated my answer. Basically, you'll have to make your own eventID. If you can logically do that, then it can be grouped. Questions?

Comment: Perfect. Well explained and easy to understand what is going on. This is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry it took me a while to reply, silly errors meant I ended up debugging for way too long. Thank you very much, PowerUser!